# react sentry normalizeDepth is not working correct

Tags: reactjs, sentry

I have a problem with showing deep nested objects with sentry in react.
[This link](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/issues/1964) specifies that normalizeDepth will fix the problem but I have a problem with that.
I use normalizeDepth with value of **1000** and use SentryErrorBoundary to sent unexpected error of axios but it didn't work.
These are what I did.

```
Sentry.init({
        dsn: sentryDSN,
        integrations: [
            new Integrations.BrowserTracing({
                routingInstrumentation: Sentry.reactRouterV5Instrumentation(browserHistory),
                ...(isProdMode ? { tracingOrigins: [clientDomain] } : {}),
            }),
        ],
        tracesSampleRate: 1.0,
        release: appVersion,
        normalizeDepth: 1000,
    });


////////////////////////////////

import { ErrorBoundary } from '@sentry/react';
const SentryErrorBoundary: FC = ({ children }) => <ErrorBoundary fallback={null}>{children}</ErrorBoundary>;
```

And this is the result in sentry (extra part)

```
{
    data: {
           errors: {
                    personal_info: [Object], 
                    store_info: [Object]
                   }, 
           message: Form is not valid.
          }
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

React version: 16.13.1

Sentry/react version: 5.24.2

Sentry version: 8.22.0